# SQL case statement comparing date1 to date2, output date2

Tags: sql

I'm relatively new to SQL and am more familiar with Excel. I am trying to compare two dates from two different columns (and tables) and haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I have read posts/done google searches without finding an answer.

Examples:

```
select table1.userID,
table1.date1,
case 
     when table1.date1 = table2.date2 
     then table2.date2 end
from table1
left join table2
on table1.userID = table2.userID

select table1.userID,
table1.date1,
case 
     when table1.date1 > table2.date2 
     then table2.date 2 end
from table1
left join table2
on table1.userID = table2.userID
```

The output I am looking in example 1 will tell me if for a each user that had an appointment on a particular day, did they also have a test completed on that day. Table 1 contains all the user IDs and all their appointment dates, and table 2 contains user IDs and test dates.

For example 2 I am looking to see if a test happened any time after a date of diagnosis (table 1 has diagnosis dates, table 2 has test dates).

I was able to accomplish the first example using two queries, one per table, then used excel to indicate if the ID/date combination from table 1 was also in table 2. Please help me figure out how to write this in SQL! :)

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: It's an ODBC database that I'm accessing through DBeaver (it's an electronic health record and I have read only access so I can't create tables/views)

Comment: I suggest to add data in your question - data before(raw) query and data you expect to get with the query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  "compare" is quite broad.

Comment: You are missing the "else" conditions in your case statements.  However, I think you will also want to add the date comparison in your left joins to avoid duplicate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.  Try:

```
select 
table1.userID,
table1.date1,
table2.date2
from 
table1
left join table2 on table1.userID = table2.userID
where table1.date1 = table2.date2
-- this select statement will show all records where the date is the same.
-- you may have to amend the WHERE clause depending on your date field datatype



select 
table1.userID,
table1.date1,
table2.date2
from table1
left join table2 on table1.userID = table2.userID
where table1.date2 > table2.date1 
-- this select statement will show all records where the date exists and is larger.
-- you may have to amend the WHERE clause depending on your date field datatype
```

Without sample data I was confused with date1 and date2 so you will have to review to make sure that it is taking the correct date fields.

Comment: The only caveat is the potential for duplicate rows.

Comment: Correct but it is very hard to understand without knowing the full process or how the data is acquired and stored.  The submitter was close, just needed the WHERE statement.

Comment: Actually I misread your answer. The `where` condition needs to be moved up into the join clause.

Comment: No. Filtering on the inner table after a left join will reduce it to an inner join. Presumably there can be appointments without any tests.

Comment: It depends on how the database structure is defined.  From reading the original question: 'Table 1 contains all the user IDs and all their appointment dates, and table 2 contains user IDs and test dates'.  Yes, you would get duplicate rows if the USERID has more than one appointment but if the USERID is unique for each appointment it will work as expected. Its hard to know until we see actual data.